# How to tag user(s) in comment via facebook php sdk?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to tag user(s) inside page post comments.

```
$fb_id = 'facebook_user_id_here';
$fb_name = 'facebook_user_name_and_surname_here';
$request = new FacebookRequest(
    $this->session,
    'POST',
    $comment,
    array(
         'access_token' => $this->page_access_token, //it is access token of my page
         'message       => "Text here @[".$fb_id.":1:".$fb_name."]"
          )
  );
```

It shows only name and surname without Fb profile URL.

Comment: You can not tag users in comments via API.

Comment: I wonder if there's a permission or any sort of policy we can work on to have this available. It's freaking hard to contact Facebook... Sometimes feel like they don't want developers to use FB stuff :/

Answer (score 0):

Like CBroe mentions in his comment, at this time this is not possible using the API.

For reference, this is called "mentioning" or "mention tagging", and personal profiles can only do this in messages on open graph actions ([docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-actions#mentions)).

Pages can also mention other pages in comments. ([docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/object/comments#pubfields))